# how to display JSON data on web page

Tags: html, css, json

So I'm just trying to figure out how to display the data from my Data.json file on my web page in the input box under the header (h1) Temperature (Degrees Celsius). I'm looking for the simplest way possible.

here's my html

```
  <!doctype html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card.css">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Filtered Input</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <h1>Temperature (Degrees Celsius)</h1>
    <label>Enter List of Temperatures in Degrees Celsius here</label>  

    <input type="text" id='Data.json'>


    <h2>Temperature (Degrees Farenheit)</h2>

    <label>Enter List of Temperatures in Degrees Farenheit here</label> 
    <input type="text" id='new_element'> 

</body>
```

and my css

```
  h1 {
 padding: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #1abc9c;
 color: white;
 font-size: 40px;
 }

h2 {
padding: 60px;
text-align: center;
background: #1abc9c;
color: white;
font-size: 40px;

}
```

and here's my Data.json

```
 [
  {
   "1": 23,
   "2": 30,
   "3": 40,
   "4": 41,
   "5": 19
  }
 ]
```

Comment: The simplest way would be to copy your JSON and paste it into your HTML file.

Answer (score 1):

All You have to do is get the element by ID in the appropriate place and then call the JSON into a variable you can use .

```js
var Data =  [  {   "1": 23,   "2": 30,   "3": 40,   "4": 41,   "5": 19  } ];


let temp = document.getElementById('temp');
temp.innerHTML = Data[0]["1"];


let data1 = document.getElementById('Data.json')
data1.onchange = function(){

temp.innerHTML = Data[0][data1.value];
};
```

```css
h1 {
 padding: 60px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #1abc9c;
 color: white;
 font-size: 40px;
 }

h2 {
padding: 60px;
text-align: center;
background: #1abc9c;
color: white;
font-size: 40px;

}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="card.css">
  <html lang="en">
  <head>


    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title>Filtered Input</title>

  </head>

  <body>

    <div id="root"></div>

    <h1 id='temp'>Temperature (Degrees Celsius)</h1>
    <label>Enter List of Temperatures in Degrees Celsius here</label>  

    <input type="text" id='Data.json'>


    <h2>Temperature (Degrees Farenheit)</h2>

    <label>Enter List of Temperatures in Degrees Farenheit here</label> 
    <input type="text" id='new_element'> 

</body>
```

Comment: That works! But I was told that I need to post the data from Data.json.

Comment: Ok so updated my answers to reflect change the number then click off the input and it will update

Answer (score 0):

Simple...

```
let n = [{
      "1": 23,
      "2": 30,
      "3": 40,
      "4": 41,
      "5": 19
}];

document
  .getElementById('temps')
  .value = JSON.stringify(n);
```

HTML (just change your input id)

```
...
    <input type="text" id='temps'> 
...
```

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve it by using Jquery

```
$.getJSON( "yourPath/data.json", function( data ) {
  var items = [];
  $.each( data, function( key, val ) {
    items.push( "key:" + key + "value:" + val );
  });

  $('#yourId').val(item);
});
```